# Open source of assertion automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I used to work with VS 2008 but I am missing the following feature in VS 2010 when debugging MFC C++ app:

- whenever an assertion occurs, VS 2008 automatically opens the source file and focus the line with an assertion expression
- in VS 2010 I have to mark the file name and line of assertion and then manually open the source file and scroll to the expression

Is there some option or registry setting how to enable such behaviour in VS2010 like it works in VS 2008 ?

Comment: Works for me right out-of-the-box. What happens for you instead?

Answer (score 1):

The first setting that really matters in in the Project + Properties, General page, "Use of MFC".  You'll have no trouble if you select the "Use MFC in a static library" setting.  This causes the linker to generate the debugger .pdb file entries for MFC symbols, giving the debugger an easy time to find the MFC source code files on your machine.

This isn't always practical however, the "Use MFC in a shared library" setting is the normal one.  Which will load the MFC dll from c:\windows\system32, put there when you installed VS.  Getting a .pdb for this DLL requires enabling the Microsoft symbol server, Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols.  Press F1 to get config help for this setting page.

You can verify this worked out by using Debug + Windows + Modules while debugging and checking the Symbol File column for mfc100xx.dll.  Right-clicking the module and Symbol Load Information provides additional info, showing which directories were searched to find the .pdb

A further complication is that the .pdb that the debugger will download was created on a build server in Redmond which had the source code files installed in f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc.  Obviously not the directory where you have them installed.  The IDE will prompt you for the actual source code directory.  This prompt is often highly confuzzling so clicking Cancel on the dialog is a common thing to do.  You now however bought the farm, the IDE remembers that you cancelled this dialog and won't prompt you again.  You reset that by deleting the hidden .suo file in the solution directory.